# Bind click event to ajaxify form button

Tags: theming, javascript

how the title says I would like to trigger javascript (jQuery) event from generated Drupal form button. I already add an *id* to the button and added the javascript in theme file like so:

```
$form['dialogCreateButton'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button', 
    '#value' => t('Create'),
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'form_kalendar_dialog_validate',
        'progress' => array(
            'type' => 'throbber', // needs to be defined
            'message' => t("Please wait..."), // instead of a message insert a javascript
        ),
    ),
);
```

and the javascript:

```
jQuery("#edit-dialogsavebutton").bind('click',function(event) {
    if(jQuery("#dialog-event-title").val().length == 0){
        focusElement.children("#eventTitle").text('(No title)');
    }else{
        focusElement.children("#eventTitle").text( jQuery("#dialog-event-title").val() );
    }
    jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

also with Drupal js:

```
Drupal.behaviors.rr = {

    attach: function(context, settings) {
        jQuery('#form-kalendar-dialog').once().ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
            console.log( event );
        });
    }
}
```

Only after several clicks the event is triggered, it acts very strange...

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to do? Or even simplify the use-case and question accordingly? It would make it easier to help. Is the form button you mention in the question the '#edit-dialogsavebutton'? What is the relation to the 'dialogCreateButton' FAPI button? Is it the same? Cheers

Comment: I want to make changes on DOM and In DB in the same time without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax callback function must to have an **ajax_command_invoke** function witch trigger an custom made function in **JS** side like so:

```
function form_kalendar_dialog_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'customMethod', array('Custom Method Arg.'));
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

JS

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.customMethod = function(arg) {
    // Custom JS goes here.
    console.write(arg);
  };
}) (jQuery);
```

The answer whas here: [Tlattimore blog](https://tlattimore.com/blog/executing-a-custom-jquery-method-in-a-drupal-ajax-callback/)